# How does Python process a statement with both assignment and a comparison?

Tags: python, operators

I've got the following line:

`group_index = apps["special_groups"] == group`

From my understanding, `group_index` is being assigned the value in `apps["special_groups"]`. Then I see the == operator, but what does it do with the result? Or is it comparing `apps["special_groups"]` to group first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Python [Evaluation Order](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) documentation:

> Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

So it first evaluates `apps["special_groups"] == group`, then assigns the result of this to `group_index`.

Comment: Beat me by less than a minute! Shouldn't have stopped for that sip of water :P

Answer (score 1):

From the Python docs, [Section 5.14](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

Therefore it evaluates the right-hand side, `apps["special_groups"] == group`, first, and then it assigns this result to the left-hand side, `group_index`.

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the value of the boolean comparison [`True` or `False`] to the LHS variable `group_index`.